# Show that $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is discontinuous exactly at all $\xi \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Hello I again had a little task to show whats described in my title.
It would be helpful, if someone could again check my reasoning and if my task was successful or not :) and if not, give me some constructive advice :)
Also I do look for someone who could more frequently look over my exercises, since im at the moment studying mechanical engineering and want to switch to maths, but I can do the switch only in winter, so teach maths myself, and there are never solutions to tasks in textbooks :(

**My attempt:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$

Lets first choose any $\xi_1,\xi_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $|\xi_2-\xi_1|=1$

Let $\xi_1 < \xi_2$ we show that $\forall x \in (\xi_1,\xi_2)$ our $f$ is continuous:

$\forall \epsilon >0\,\, \exists \delta>0 \,\,\forall x \in (\xi_1,\xi_2):(|x-x_0|<\delta)\Longrightarrow(|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon)$

We know that $\forall x,y \in(\xi_1,\xi_2):|f(x)-f(y)|=0$

So our $\epsilon-\delta-$Criterium always holds in the given intervall! Which tells that

$f$ is continuous on any open intervall between two adjacent integers.

Now we just need to show that at any $\xi \in \mathbb{Z}$ the function is discontinuous.

$\lim\limits_{x \searrow \xi_2}\lfloor x\rfloor=\xi_2$ and $\lim\limits_{x \nearrow \xi_2}\lfloor x\rfloor=\xi_1 \Longrightarrow \lim\limits_{x \searrow \xi_2}\lfloor x\rfloor\ne \lim\limits_{x \nearrow \xi_2}\lfloor x\rfloor \Longrightarrow f$ is discontinuous at any $\xi \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spare some work, but you seem to have the right ideas.

Let $\zeta\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, over the interval $(\zeta,\zeta+1)$ the function is constant and its value is $\zeta$. Since the interval is open, the function is continuous over it.

In different words: if $x$ is not an integer, there is a full neighborhood of $x$ where the function is constant, so $f$ is certainly continuous at $x$.

Thus it only remains to establish continuity or not at $\zeta$. For $\zeta<x<\zeta+1$ we have $f(x)=\zeta$; for $\zeta-1<x<\zeta$, we have $f(x)=\zeta-1$.

Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to\zeta^-}f(x)=\zeta-1\ne\lim_{x\to\zeta^+}f(x)=\zeta
$$